# Codeigniter - Send mail but' can't load page

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I make a function to send mail with Codeigniter. But i receive email but webpage can't load. Please help me. If i remove $options and function, it can load page

```
$options = array(
            'currentMail' => 1,
            'title' => 'tretretretetre dfg dsfsdfsf',
            'toEmail' => 'abc@gmail.com',
            'content' => 'fds fds fds dsfdsds fds fdsfds fdsf ds',
        );

        $this->load->library('email');
        $currentMail = $options['currentMail'];
        $mail = $this->p_model->GetInfoEmail($currentMail);
        $cf = $this->p_model->GetConfigEmail($currentMail);
        $config = Array(
         'protocol' => $cf['mail_type_protocol'],
         'smtp_port' => (int)$cf['mail_type_smtp_port'],
         'smtp_host' => $cf['mail_type_smtp_host'],
         'smtp_user' => $mail['mail_user'],
         'smtp_pass' => $mail['mail_password'],
         'mailtype' => 'html',
         'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
         'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_mailtype("html");

        $emailSend = 'no-reply@'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; 
        $this->email->from($emailSend, $options['title']);
        $this->email->to($options['toEmail']);
        if($options['cc'])
          $this->email->cc($options['cc']);
        $this->email->subject($options['title']);
        $this->email->message($options['content']);
        $this->email->send();

$this->load->view('index');
```

[image]

Comment: `$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");` try using with `$this->email->intialize($config)` because already loaded the email library and you have also set the mailtype

Comment: `$this->load->library('email', $config);$this->email->set_mailtype("html");` instead of this try using `$this->email->initialize($config)` because you already loaded the email library.

Comment: I had tried edit it: $this->load->library('email', $config); to $this->email->initialize($config);. But now, my webpage can't load and email can't send

Comment: try `redirect('controller_name/method_name')`.

Comment: problem could also be related to browser or browser plugin